# Should all projects in a solution have the same character encoding?

Tags: unicode, multibyte

For a big solution containing ten or so projects, should all the projects have the same characterset (unicode)?

What are the possible consequences of the projects having different character encoding?

Comment: You should probably specify the platform, IDE, lanugage, etc.

Comment: :), sorry for late reply. the Platform is win7, the IDE is vs2010. And the language is the cobination of  C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

Many strange things are possible - but I do not think you are interested in that. I believe all projects should use the same encoding to reduce the number of errors. This encoding should be UTF-8, to be compatible with the rest of the world.

The best how-to info source on the subject is http://utf8everywhere.org.

Comment: Thanks,  someone said this could co-exist, maybe there is some C4819 warning coming out. http://bbs.csdn.net/topics/390366754